# Unable to assign rowTemplate via javascricpt

Tags: angular, ui-grid

I am trying to edit the template of the row based on some data in the ui-grid.

Example:

column definition -->

```
$scope.gridOptions: [
                  rowTemplate : '<div ng-class={\'my-css-class\':{{row.entity.deletedBy!=NULL}}}></div>';
                  columnDef : [{ name: 'deletedBy',
                                displayName: 'deletedBy',
                                field: 'deletedBy'
                                visible: false }];
```

css -->

```
.my-css-class { color: blue; }
```

The rowTemplate wont get implemented. Am i missing something here?

I am using this as reference : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20317%20Custom%20Templates

Answer (score 0):

I think you should include the default rowTemplate contents in your custom rowTemplate,  something like:

```
 <div
  ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
  ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + \'-\' + col.uid + \'-cell\'"
  class="ui-grid-cell"
  ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader, \'my-css-class\':{{row.entity.deletedBy!=NULL}} }"
  role="{{col.isRowHeader ? \'rowheader\' : \'gridcell\'}}"
  ui-grid-cell>
</div>
```